# How to set view of a label in perforce using command-line?

Tags: perforce, p4v

```
p4 tag -g -l "release_1.0" //my_depot/...
```

Seeing `view` of this label in `p4v` shows other depots also.

How to set view of a label using command-line ?

Answer (score 1):

The 'p4 tag' command will either create a new label spec, if the label spec doesn't already exist, or will use the existing label spec, if it has already been created.

So if you want to control the view for the 'release_1.0' label, you use the 'p4 label -o' and 'p4 label -i' commands.

For example, you could construct a plain text file with the following contents:

```
Label: release_1.0
Owner: bryan
Options: unlocked noautorelad
View:
    //my_depot/...
```

and then you could use this file as the standard input to 'p4 label -i' to set the view for your label to be only '//my_depot/...'